# Write Inputs to CSV

Tags: php, csv

Im new to PHP and cant figure this out.

I have 2 inputs(Name and email). I need to write it to CSV file and download on click. I found out that i need fputcsv() function and to form array of arrays...

But somehow i cant see how to form that array correctly...  Can someone give me a hint?

Im already wirting to txt file... but simply cant transform it to csv...

```
public function invokeAction(CakeRequest $request){
         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if(isset($_POST['subName']) && isset($_POST['subEmail'])) {
            $data = $_POST['subName'] . '-' . $_POST['subEmail'] . "\n";
            $ret = file_put_contents('../tmp/subs.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            unset($_POST['subName']);
            unset($_POST['subEmail']);
         }   
    }
```

Comment: @Carsten: _“No need for fputcsv or anything”_ – yes, need. Your simple solution will break as soon as one of the values contains the delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is replace the dash between subName and subEmail with a "," and rename your file to subs.csv.

```
public function invokeAction(CakeRequest $request){
         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if(isset($_POST['subName']) && isset($_POST['subEmail'])) {
            $data = $_POST['subName'] . ',' . $_POST['subEmail'] . "\n";
            $ret = file_put_contents('../tmp/subs.csv', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            unset($_POST['subName']);
            unset($_POST['subEmail']);
         }   
    }
```

CSV is not a special file format. It's just plain text with a certain format.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Wim for the answer. My solution is almost the same but just in case someone needs it:

```
public function invokeAction(CakeRequest $request){
         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if(isset($_POST['subName']) && isset($_POST['subEmail'])) {
            // $data = $_POST['subName'] . '-' . $_POST['subEmail'] . "\n";
            $subName=$_POST['subName'];
            $subEmail=$_POST['subEmail'];
            $subs[] = array("$subName","$subEmail");
            //$ret = file_put_contents('../tmp/subs.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            $fp = fopen('../webroot/subs.csv', 'a');
            foreach ($subs as $fields) {
                fputcsv($fp, $fields);
            }
            fclose($fp);
            unset($_POST['subName']);
            unset($_POST['subEmail']);
         } 
    }
```